# Best practice for data access to third-party applications using .NET Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, entity-framework

I'm building a customization for an existing third-party application.  My code runs in the same .NET app pool and is on the same server as the third-party app.

I dont have any access to their data models and there is no api.  I've been writing SQL queries and developing out WCF services for my customizations.  This works but it feels 'gross'.  Below is an example:

```
public DLPDetail GetEventDetail(int id)
    {
        DLPDetail detail = new DLPDetail();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DLP"].ToString());
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT compound_path, FILE_MATCH_ID FROM E_ABSTRACT_FILE_MATCH WHERE EVENT_ID = '" + id + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            detail.Name = reader.GetString(0);
            detail.FileMatchId = reader.GetInt64(1).ToString();
        }

        return detail;
    }
```

I wondering if there is a better approach I could be taking using something like entity framework or something like that.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few recommendations:

1. If you're directly querying a third party database, you need to be
   **very** careful when executing queries against it.  If you start passing strings based on user input into those queries you're
   opening yourself up for a SQL injection.  The last thing you want to
   deal with is angry users and a vendor telling you that you can't get
   support because you used the product in an unsupported fashion.
2. There's nothing wrong with writing plain ol' SQL or stored procedures.  You don't *have* to use the Entity Framework (EF) for every project
3. That said, the EF is a very nice feature set.  If you want classes populated with the data you retrieve from the database it's a great choice.  Or if you want to populate classes to send off and get updated on the database without having to write SQL, you can do that too.
4. If you need to squeeze out *every* last drop of performance, then perhaps writing SQL yourself is the way to go so you have full control of what's being executed, making sure execution plans are correct, etc.  If you don't need that level of control, perhaps give EF a try.

Comment: Great suggestions!!!  Few notes:

1) I'm not actually doing any puts against their database, only reads :) but great suggestion!

2,3)  These third-party apps are already my minor little services are coming back 500x faster already so EF will still seem amazing speeds even if it is slower.

Comment: I use EF in a variety of production applications (as do other developers here); so it can certainly meet performance requirements! It just depends on what level of control you need (how far down the stack you wish to develop is another way of thinking about it). I used this as a guide for getting started with EF: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application. Perhaps it will be of use to you.

Comment: I'm more of a front-end guy so EF is AMAZING imo ... I'd prefer something like a backend as a service architecture haha ...